# Где найти сервис-планировщик?

Tags: php, javascript, cron

Есть сайт https://ru.stackoverflow.com/Index.php В PHP файле прописанн код который узнает температуру и добавляет в БД. Чтобы это произошло в браузере нажимаешь на F5 или обновить и PHP код срабатывает 1 раз.

Так вот.
Мне нужно сделать так чтобы, каждые 10 минут весь этот процесс происходил. Как это сделать?

Слышал о Cron, но они все платные, Есть бесплатные варианты?

Comment: Вопрос очень интересный, но не уточненный... Что значит для Вас "Запуск сайта раз в 10 минут"?

Comment: Все просто. Кто - то или что - то делает переход на ссылке допустим http://ru.stackoverflow.com/Index.php. А в php файле прописанн некий код. Допустим Запись в БД некой инфы.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял. Если нет то "Запуск сайта раз в 10 минут" это означает что за час будет 6 запросов к сайту, которые запрашиваются через 10 минут.
60 минут / 10 мин= 6 раз

Comment: Вас интересует выполнение этого php кода раз в 10 минут? Или Вам нужно, чтобы определенная URL была посещена в это время?

Comment: "Где найти крона?" - это что-то очень странное, равно как и "запуск сайта раз в 10 минут". Если вам нужно запускать PHP-скрипт раз в 10 минут, а деньги на нормальный функционал хостинга тратить почему-то жалко, то можно использовать костыль в стиле бесконечно (по крайней мере, если на сервере нет ограничения по времени и памяти работы скрипта) работающего PHP-скрипта, в котором стоит `sleep` на нужный период простоя. Второй вариант - автоматически периодически обращаться к данному скрипту. Для этого можно использовать соответствующие сервисы.

Comment: Третий вариант - запускать PHP-скрипт из него же, обращаясь на нужный URL (скрипта) спустя нужную задержку, созданную всё тем же `sleep`'ом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте этот вариант. Это [web cron](http://www.webcron.org/) что-то вроде веб версии крона.
А также взгляните на эти, может помогут:

- SetCronJob - www.setcronjob.com
- Cronless - cronless.com
- EasyCron - www.easycron.com
- Online Cron Jobs - www.onlinecronjobs.com
- Corntab - www.corntab.com
- getCron - www.getcron.com

Comment: Автор, опишите функционал поподробнее, интересный сервис...

Comment: @lev09, Спасибо!)

Comment: @GrayHoax Могу лишь сказать что эта веб аналог известного планировщика CRON. Многого сказать не могу, так как сам никогда не пользовался.

Answer (score 3):

Если Вы про CRON (не склоняемое в рус языке), как приложение-планировщик, то не совсем понятен вопрос, а именно, что вы будете запускать, если планировщик будет на отличной от хостинга с сайтом машине?

Сайт в интернет не требует запуска (в зависимости от реализации). Он просто есть! Возможно вы имеете ввиду какой-то отдельный функционал? Уточните вопрос и я обновлю ответ :)

**UPD**:

Посещение определенной URL можно настроить в мониторинге, например в бесплатном или условно-бесплатном. Попробуйте настроить [Site24x7](https://www.site24x7.com/). После регистрации можно бесплатно настроить 5 "мониторов". Если создать `WebSite Monitor`, то робот будет проверять указанный URL раз в указанное время. К тому же, если в Вашем коде php возникнет ошибка, Site24x7 сообщит о ней по почте.

Обратите внимание, что посещение URL мониторингом может происходить не строго раз в 10 минут (если укажете это время), а с некоторой погрешностью.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите мониторить доступность сайта (хотя из текущей формулировки вопроса это до конца не очевидно), то вот сходу пара способов:

[С помощью Google Docs](http://habrahabr.ru/post/141686/)

[Скрипт на php+mysql](http://habrahabr.ru/company/webprojects/blog/97634/)